# How do I create an exception for mod security?

Tags: mod-security

When I checked the logs, I found Mod_security blocking some files necessary
for the site operation. So far, I disabled it per domain in the apache configuration file.
I want to only disable certain rules on certain pages.The implementation examples I read are specific to red hat and other distros.
I run Centos 5 with apache 2.8 and mod_security 2 (the server hosts multiple sites)

On centos, the loaded mod_security is included on top like this:

```
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.conf"
```

The above file calls modsec2.user.conf that is found in the same directory.

Here's what I've done so far:

My server does not have a directory called modsecurity.d for me to create a file like this:

```
/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/modsecurity_localrules.conf
```

So I created a file named:

```
whitelist.conf
```

in:

```
 /usr/local/apache/conf/
```

then I added an include to it in:

```
/etc/httpd/conf/modsec2.conf/
```

the rules look like:

```
<LocationMatch "/wp-admin/post.php">
  SecRuleRemoveById 950006
</LocationMatch>
```

But the rules are not working. I wonder if whitelist.conf was placed in the right place.

I then created 2 files:

```
modsecurity_crs_15_customrules.conf
modsecurity_crs_60_customrules.conf
```

and placed them in:

```
/home/cpeasyapache/src/modsecurity-apache_2.5.12/rules
```

The above path is where I found:

```
modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf
```

that contains main rules though I haven't seen it called by any other file.

Base rules are found in:

```
/home/cpeasyapache/src/modsecurity-apache_2.5.12/rules/base_rules
```

It seems my mod_security is installed and configured with minimal functionality.am thinking to add this to httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule security2_module>
Include /home/cpeasyapache/src/modsecurity-apache_2.5.12/rules/modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf
Include /home/cpeasyapache/src/modsecurity-apache_2.5.12/rules/base_rules/*.conf
Include /home/cpeasyapache/src/modsecurity-apache_2.5.12/rules/optional_rules/*.conf
Include /home/cpeasyapache/src/modsecurity-apache_2.5.12/rules/modsecurity_crs_15_customrules.conf
Include /home/cpeasyapache/src/modsecurity-apache_2.5.12/rules/modsecurity_crs_60_customrules.conf
</IfModule>
```

How do you guys do it on your end?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If none of those rules is working, a quick and dirty way to check whether the file is loaded at all is to have a tiny typo inside (e.g. have one `ecRuleRemoveById` instead of `SecRuleRemoveById`). If you then do a `service apache2 reload` and it still loads fine (not showing any error), the file was not included at all.